# Vuetify Month Picker control is triggering the change event for a separate v-select control

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm experiencing an issue with a Vuetify month picker control and a v-select control.  When I click on the month control, the change event for the v-select is triggered.  Why would a separate control trigger the change event of another control.  I have a codepen link below to help display the issue.  You'll see when you click on the calendar control, the changed event for the v-select will fire and write "Holler" to the console.  Any ideas??  Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/scooby0344/pen/zYjGQaR?editors=1011

```
<div>https://codepen.io/scooby0344/pen/zYjGQaR?editors=1011</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the link

Comment: I provided the link.  Stackoverflow deleted it upon post.